# How does rqt_pose_view plugin work?

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK this might be trivial but I just can't get it to work.

When I enable the plugin in rqt, I can see the square and the 3 arrows in 3D, I can drag and move to see them from different angles, but, how do I connect it to my topic?
There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the topic name.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101446/how-does-rqt_pose_view-plugin-work?/) by [mathieu-wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/8831/mathieu-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry about the long delay for this answer.
I updated the wiki page for this plugin to give a short introduction:
http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_pose_view

Basically it just displays the orientation part of a geometry_msgs/Pose message.
You have to drag and drop the topic onto it...

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2